# C++ Function Not Converting Decimal Point as Part of the Number (Input Validation)

Tags: c++, validation, for-loop, input, floating-point

How can I modify this function so that it includes a decimal place as part of the inputted numerical value if the decimal is not the first position of the input? Realistically speaking, the number should have one decimal place which can either be the first position (index[0]) or any other position in the number. For example, if I input 7.3, it should return back 7.3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double ReadDouble(string prompt)
{
    string input;
    string convert;
    bool isValid=true;

    do {
        isValid = true;

            cout << prompt;
            cin >> input;

    if (isdigit(input[0]) == 0 && input[0] != '.' && input[0] != '+' && input[0] != '-' && input[0] != '+')
    {
        cout << "Error! Input was not a number.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        convert = input.substr(0,1);
    }

    long len = input.length();
        for (long index = 1; index < len && isValid == true; index++)
        {
            if (isdigit(input[index]) == 0){
                cout << "Error! Input was not an integer.\n";
                isValid=false;
            }
            else if (input[index] == '.') {
                ;
            }
            else {
                convert += input.substr(index,1);
            }
        }
        } while (isValid == false);


    double returnValue=atof(convert.c_str());
    return returnValue;
}


int main()
{
    double x = ReadDouble("Enter a value: ");
    cout << "Your value: " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to what you asked, but prefer `convert += input[index];` over building a substring of one character.

Comment: Do you _have_ to do it manually or do you just want it to work? ... and why are you validating a floating point input and require it to be an integer? Do you want a `double` or do you want an integer?

Comment: I have to do it manually even though at this point I just want it to work

Comment: You do know that `atoi` returns an `int`, right?  Maybe you were looking for `atof`.

Comment: `strtol()/stoi()` provides more error checking potential than `atoi()`.

Comment: userh16xx0 Posting some samples of good/bad input would improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

[atof does what you need already](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/), so if you are just trying to get it working, ReadDouble can just execute atof:

```
double ReadDouble(string prompt)
{
    string input;

    cout << prompt;
    cin >> input;
    return atof(input);
}
```